# How does Naruto's right arm work?

Tags: naruto

## Spoiler alert for those who haven't finished the manga or the anime

> After the Naruto and Sasuke fight (in Naruto volume 72: Uzumaki Naruto chapters 694-698), both of them lost one of their arms above the elbow. [image] After a while, Naruto got a fake arm (I think Sasuke didn't) which was wrapped in bandages (it was shown in the rest of the mangas, The Last: Naruto the Movie, and Boruto: Naruto the Movie).
>  [image][image][image]

It was shown in the movies and in the manga that his arm can move and act like his arm used to before he lost it, so he can use it for eating, writing, carrying things, holding things, waving hand signs, releasing jutsus, etc.. But how does it work? I know it was created by Tsunade, and since she's an excellent medical ninja she could have found a way or something, but was it ever mentioned of how it worked or anything? I mean, I know the Naruto Universe evolved over time and stuff, so I guess they found a way to create body part that works like they used to.

Comment: Hashirama's cell ? Everyone think Danzo lost an arm, but in fact he already fix it using Hashirama's cell.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena so your telling me Tsunade used her grandfather's cells to make Naruto's fake arm?!? What?!?

Comment: Whats wrong with it ? I recall Tsunade have soft spot for Naruto. So She want to help Naruto ascension as Hokage by giving him a hand~

if you're not agree with it there's always Kyuubi's Regen + Uzumaki's Longevity + Best Medic(s) available for him.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena first of all, was the "giving him a hand" pun intended or not because that's pretty funny, and second, that's just creepy I mean she's using her own grandfather's cells!!! And where would she get them from, Orochimaru, or not because she can't use her's, right?

Comment: i recall they let Orochimaru & Kabuto live. I bet they do something for their freedom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki) :

> Naruto loses his right arm after the Fourth Shinobi World War, though it is later replaced by a fully maneuverable prosthetic arm made of Hashirama Senju's cells, wrapped completely in bandages

I'm not sure it makes sense that it is prosthetic and made up of Hashirama's cells, since a prosthetic limb is, by definition, artificial. The definition for prosthetic on [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prosthesis) is

> an artificial device that replaces a missing or injured part of the body

Perhaps there are both organic and artificial components.

Well, regardless, Narutopedia states that the arm is fully maneuverable. I could be wrong on this point, but I don't think Naruto has any trouble moving the arm. So with the arm moving the same as a normal arm and with it having organic components (Hashirama's cells), I think it is reasonable to assume it is connected to his nervous system, thus allowing it to function as a normal arm.

Comment: Either that (connected to his nervous system) or he is able to control the prosthetic arm by molding chakra.

Comment: That would probably require hand signs. Even if it didn't, using chakra to control the arm would look more clumsy than moving it using the nervous system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is mad of completely hashirama cells and because of that it is technically not a prosthetic arm. If you want to know why it glows continue reading. I think Naruto's arm glows because of chakra absorbing cloths that are on it (examples of it glowing are when he puts his arm in Hinata's body and undose the jutsu that Toneri Ōtsutsuki put on Hinata) Toneri Ōtsutsuki is the second person to have the Tenseigan the first person was Hamura Ōtsutsuki but all of that is another story that you can find here on Narutopedia!